# Ansible: copy template only when destination file does not exist

Tags: ansible

I'm using `Ansible 1.6.6` to provision my machine.

There is a [template task](http://docs.ansible.com/template_module.html) in my playbook that creates destination file from Jinja2 template:

```yaml
tasks:
    - template: src=somefile.j2 dest=/etc/somefile.conf
```

I do not want to replace `somefile.conf` if it already exists. Is it possible with Ansible? If so, how?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can check for file existence using stat, and then use template only if file does not exist.

```
tasks:
  - stat: path=/etc/somefile.conf
    register: st
  - template: src=somefile.j2 dest=/etc/somefile.conf
    when: not st.stat.exists
```

Comment: There is now an option `force` to the [Ansible template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#parameter-force) that does precisely that. This option was introduced a long time ago (years), but I don't find when in the patch notes.

Answer (score 69):

You can just use the *force* param of the template module with `force=no`

```yml
tasks:
  - name: Create file from template if it doesn't exist already.
    template: 
      src: somefile.j2
      dest: /etc/somefile.conf
      force: no
```

From the [Ansible template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#parameter-force) docs:

> force: the default is yes, which will replace the remote file when
> contents are different than the source. If no, the file will only be
> transferred if the destination does not exist.

Other answers use `stat` because the *force* parameter was added after they were written.

Comment: my answer uses stat, because at the time of the question/answer there was no force argument avaialable for template

Comment: i was hoping to use this for a full path of files (not templates), hence it looks like template doesnt work

Comment: @BrianThomas, I'm not sure what you mean but if you want to apply this to a file copy instead of a template you can use copy module, is supports the force parameter. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html

Answer (score 11):

You can first check that the destination file exists or not and then make a decision based on the output of it's result.

```
tasks:
  - name: Check that the somefile.conf exists
    stat:
      path: /etc/somefile.conf
    register: stat_result

  - name: Copy the template, if it doesnt exist already
    template:
      src: somefile.j2
      dest: /etc/somefile.conf
    when: stat_result.stat.exists == False
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it names it's tasks :)

Answer (score -1):

According to me, the easiest solution is to use the attribute "force=no" from the template module

Comment: Back when this question was asked, the ```force``` parameter was not implemented. Today, this answer describes best practice!